# An extra input appears

Tags: c, input, scanf

For example when I input 2 for num1 and 3 for num2, I expect to get 8 for the output as soon as I enter the second number. However, the program expects me to input one more integer, and I just input a random number like 242 and it still outputs 8, which means that it does not affect the result. So my question is why is there the third input?
Thank you for your help!

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int Power (int num1, int num2);

int main ()
{
    int a, b;
    puts ("Enter two numbers, a and b:\n");  
    scanf ("%i\n", &a);
    scanf ("%i\n", &b);
    printf ("%i\n", Power(a, b));
    return 0;
}

int Power (int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=num2; i++){
        sum= sum*num1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the newlines: `\n`, in your `scanf` format strings, or just use a single `scanf`, e.g.:

```
scanf("%i%i", &a, &b);
```

Or:

```
scanf ("%i", &a);
scanf ("%i", &b);
```

Comment: Even when a single `scanf` that `\n` should be removed. `scanf("%i%i", &a, &b)` is all that's necessary.

Comment: Additionally, it might make sense to note that `%i` format might give you more than you really need. I'd say `%d` would make more sense in this context. The user might be surprised to discover that `023` is actually interpreted as `19`.

Comment: Actually, [gets()](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Deprecated-string-input-functions.html#Deprecated%20string%20input%20functions) is deprecated, try the function [getline()](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html)

Comment: @AndreyT Just an addition for the OP: that is because `%i` will interpret decimal, hexadecimal, and octal depending on input. Numbers will be treated as hex if inputted with prefix `0x`, and octal if prefixed with `0`.

Comment: @cacho thanks for the reminder, I killed the bit about gets altogether

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf()` doesn't need the `"\n"`.

```
scanf ("%i", &a);
scanf ("%i", &b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the '\n' from your format string in your calls to `scanf`.